# PHP/MySQL: Detecting duplicate spam "member to member" private messages?

Tags: php, mysql, spam-prevention

I have a small dating site where members can contact other members through a private messaging system. The messages are stored in a MySQL database, so members can login and view their inbox on-site.

I'm noticing a recent problem where spam members are selecting their city within the US, but their IP address shows they are in a different country. The second red flag is they are sending between 6-10 private messages at a time to random members and the message content appears to be duplicates or near-duplicates, and they include a request to contact the spammer by an outside email address (which is included in the message).

Current countermeasures I coded in the PHP script: Members have to complete their entire profile before contacting other members. Members must wait at least 60 seconds between sending messages. Maximum of 10 messages can be sent per day (for newer members). Users can report other users and there is an auto-ban if too many reports come in, but no one is reporting the spam messages...

Does anyone have some advice on strengthen the countermeasures? I don't want good members running away from the site because of fake spammers contacting them.

Thanks

Comment: We're not here to help you (or actually do) design an anti-spam system. That's waaay too broad for this site.

Comment: email/sms confirmation, autoban if stopwords present in message, stricter requirements for non US users

Comment: Controlling the spam is a hard thing to do in any project. Put some more focus into user moderation rather spending extreme amounts of man hours to attempt to stop it all together, truth is spam will always fall through the net

Comment: Have a look at http://www.stopforumspam.com  It checks the remote IP on signup, and if listed as known forum/comment spammer, simply don't create the account, otherwise carry on.